# AngularJs Error: [ngModel:nonassign]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have started to learn AngularJS and this is what amazes me, at the beginning even a four lines of code does not work properly and I have no clue

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name='Rocky'">

Your name is {{name}}
</div>
```

On typing something in the textbox, my expression does not change.

It shows the below error in the console.

```
 TypeError: r is not a function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't initialize to `Rocky` inside `ng-model`.  Try this:

```
<div data-ng-app="">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-init="name='Rocky'">

Your name is {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: oh...got it, so ng-model can contain only variable names, right?

Comment: `ng-model` is looking for a scoped property to reference.  It then watches that property for changes.  The assignment cannot be watched effectively.

Comment: thanx this works, but what I was hoping to do is while opening the page, the input should be be prefilled with rocky, how can i do that?

Comment: `Rocky` should be prefilled when using `ng-init="name='Rocky'"`.

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign)

> This error occurs when expression the ngModel directive is bound to is a non-assignable expression.

You need to initialize using [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive. You cannot initialize using `ngModel`

> The ngInit directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope.

```
<input type="text" ng-init="name='Abhinav'" ng-model="name" />
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/w4kbp8jL/)

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-value instead of ng-model worked for me.